# Power Configuration Seems to Not Be Respected by OS

Tags: suspend, release-juno, power

Recently installed Juno based off recommendation from a friend. The issue I'm currently facing is my laptop (Dell XPS 13), even though I've configured to never suspend on both Plugged and Unplugged, it suspends after a period of time. Are there any logs I can provide that would help? I'd prefer to avoid having systemd do anything if there's a way to configure it via the options. It just *feels* like something isn't hooked up quite right.

Thank you!

Comment: I can confirm that this also happens on my T400

Comment: same here for me on older machines, Loki did not have the problem.  In Juno suspend setting simply seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    sudo su
    su - -s /bin/bash lightdm
    gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type
    dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type nothing
```

Note that if you 'sudo' instead, it won't work properly. This fixed it on my XPS 15 9560 :)

Comment: I left eOS not long after this. I posted a bug on GitHub that's still open. This particular fix didn't work for me in October but maybe it would now. I just can't afford to have basic functionality regress so badly without fixes. I understand it's a small team, so I moved on as I didn't have time to write code (and learn the language, honestly) to try and fix it. I'll check it out again once the bug is closed as fixed.